# nuxt, обработка ошибки

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть nuxt приложение, если back-end возвращает 422, то страница меняется на "Request failed with status code 422". Хотя мне надо обрабатывать и выводить ошибку, как сделать так что бы не открывалась страница - "Request failed with status code 422", при получении 422 от back-end?

Comment: необходимо обработать ошибку, использовать `.catch()` или `try...catch`, зависит от того, что используется - `Promise` или `async & await`

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли, всё решилось с помощью try...cathc.